# Function returning empty List after .clear()

Tags: java, list

I'm working on a Badge Project with NFC. Therefore I need to display all Values from a SQL Query. Currently I'm trying to sort the values by day and insert them into a new list which I want to add into another List which should contain all days.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> sort(List<String> daten) throws SQLException, ParseException {
    int i = 0;
    int position = 0;
    long firstday= parse(daten.get(0)).getTime();
    int arraysize = daten.size();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> alldays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> day = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (i <= arraygrösse) {
        if (parse(daten.get(position)).getTime() - firstday< 72000000) {
            day.add(daten.get(position));
            daten.remove(position);
        } else {
            alldays.add(day);
            firstday= parse(daten.get(0)).getTime();
            day.clear();
        }
        i++;
    }
    return alldays;
}
```

After i call the .clear() function the 'alldays' is empty([`[][][]`]
Is there another option than .clear() I also tried .removeAll() but it didn't worked either.

Comment: Where are `day` and `alldays` defined? Would expect them in this method.

Comment: What's your problem with `.clear()`?

Comment: .clear() also deletes the values in the alldays List

Comment: When you add `day` to the `alldays` List it is just like a pointer. The ArrayList in `alldays` will be deleted if you are using `.clear()`. And in the end the `alldays` List just contains empty Lists. You have to create a new Object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of day.clear() try this:

```
day = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: I had the same Problem. And exactly this one fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

When you `add(day)`, you're not adding a copy, you're adding the same `day` multiple times and so subsequent `add` and `clear` operations will affect it.

I would expect `day` and `alldays` to be defined in this method.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> sort(List<String> daten) throws SQLException, ParseException {
    int i = 0;
    int position = 0;

    //new local delarations
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> alldays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> day = new ArrayList<String>();

    long firstday= parse(daten.get(0)).getTime();
    int arraysize = daten.size();
    while (i <= arraygrösse) {
        if (parse(daten.get(position)).getTime() - firstday< 72000000) {
            day.add(daten.get(position));
            daten.remove(position);
        } else {
            alldays.add(day);
            firstday= parse(daten.get(0)).getTime();

            //don't clear the day, start a new day
            day = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        i++;
    }
    return alldays;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You always add `day` to `alldays`. So if you clear `day`, it should clear `alldays` too.

You need to allocate new array instead of `.clear()`;

```
day = new ArrayList<String>();
```